# php saving an image to postgresql and read it back is not working

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, blob

This must be common asked question, But I could not find from google. We have a table and has photo column in bytea type in postgresql. 
We are saving upcoming image with this snippet:

```
$photo->attributes = $_FILES['Photo'];
$file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($photo, 'photo');
$path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/data/' . $file->name;
$file->saveAs($path); //save the file to the $path
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($path));  //get the file content
fclose($fp);
$photo->photo = base64_encode($content);   //encode it
$photo->save();  //save the record to db
unlink(Yii::app()->basePath . '/data/' . $file->name);
```

saving seems working good.

this is where we are reading blob field from db:

```
base64_decode($data->photo) //this call is giving base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given error.
```

if I do:

```
print_r($data->photo) //I am getting: Resource id #51
```

Obviously `$data->photo` is not binary string, it is coming as a resource. Any idea how to make it work?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the code you are using to get `$data` out of the database?

Comment: @chrislondon, We are using fromework's active reader feature.  $data = Photo::model()->find('employee_id = :employee_id', array(':employee_id' => $id));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `base64` then you don't need `bytea`, you can use a regular `text` field. It'll be less efficient for disk space, but that's about it.

If you want to store the actual bytes, you don't encode it as base64, you use `pg_escape_bytea` to convert it to PostgreSQL's hex-string representation (for modern PostgreSQL versions) of `bytea` values. You use `pg_bytea_decode` when extracting the data.

If you're using PDO instead of the native PostgreSQL driver, look up how to work with bytea using PDO. You haven't actually shown your database code at all, only some wrapper for it, so it's very hard to tell what's going on.

Of course, all this only applies to PHP; most languages have separate data types for "textual data" and "binary data" that let the client library automatically convert binary data without you having to jump through escape/unescape hooks.

Answer (score 0):

For me work this solution:

Save file to DB:

```
$file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
if ($file!=null) {
    $fp = fopen($file->tempName,'r');
    $content = fread($fp,  $file->size);
    fclose($fp);
    $doc->doc=null;  //bytea field
    $doc->docname = $file->name;
    $doc->mime = $file->type;
    $doc->size = $file->size;
    $doc->save();   
    $msg = $doc->getErrors();
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('UPDATE '.
                $doc->tableName().' SET "doc"=:doc WHERE id='.$doc->id); 
    $command->bindParam(":doc", $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB); // <-- look this!
    $command->execute();
}
```

Show file from DB:

```
header('Content-Type: '.$doc->mime );
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'' . rawurlencode ($doc->docname ) );
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $doc->size);
$content = fread($doc->doc, $doc->size);
echo $content;
exit;
```